# How to access my site with different name using .HOSTS file?

Tags: dns

Is there any way, to set:

**example.com** to show my site (of course, only for my computer)..

dont know what is that called - address manipulation or something.. maybe with windows .HOSTS file?

Answer (score 0):

Windows - add string below to the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Where `127.0.0.1` is the server IP.

Linux - add the same string to the file `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: no,  in that case, **example.com** will be binded to the SERVER IP, and then server cant read what EXAMPLE.COM is, because on that hosting EXAMPLE.COM is not set up.

Comment: @tazotodua - That doesn't make any sense.  If you want to map a name to an IP address, then this is the way to do it.  If that's not what you want, then you need to specify what you want.

Comment: Well, of course, your server should be configured to work with EXAMPLE.COM, at least on the web-server virtual host level. There is no other way, because server wouldn't know how to route your request.

Comment: @SergeyBrodin thanks, your answer was the one i wanted to know!